# Shiny app doesn't recognize vector c() saying "unused argument"

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make a shinyapp using reactive object. But, for instance when I'm executing this (server, UI is ok with just a verbatimTextOutput) :

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive({
    switch(input$type,
           "a" = data_a,
           "b" = data_b)
  })

  var_quant = reactive(sort(colnames(data()[,!colnames(data())%in%c("var1","var2")])))

#I want to select variables which are not var1 and var2

  output$vector <- renderPrint({
     var_quant()
  })
})
```

But when I execute I've got this error message in appli :

```
Error : unused arguments ("var1","var2")
```

And this one in my console :

```
    Warning: Error in c: unused arguments ("var1","var2")
```

Of course, I've already checked many times if a wrote correctly the varnames.

Also and this why I don't understand, it's working when I do this (but I do not want to use this methode in my case) :

```
vars = c("var1","var2")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive({
    switch(input$type,
           "a" = data_a,
           "b" = data_b)
  })

  var_quant = reactive(sort(colnames(data()[,!colnames(data())%in%vars])))

  output$vector <- renderPrint({
     var_quant()
  })
})
```

For instance I've got the same problem with that :

```
vecteur.ts = reactive(ts(vecteur(),start = c(2012,2),end = c(2015,2),freq = 12))
```

Appli :

```
unused arguments (2012, 2)
```

Console :

```
Error in c: unused arguments (2012, 2)
```

If anyone knows how to deal with that problem... Thanks

Comment: Seems like a bug in Shiny actually. Try putting a space between %in% and c(...)  It seems as if it considers %in%c the name of a function...

Comment: Yes i was thinking about a bug, but didn't found a solution to debug ! I try what you've said

Comment: I can't reproduce. And seriously, are you checking the colnames of a data frame, to then select these columns from the data frame and extract ... the column names?  `cols <- colnames(data()); var_quant <- cols[!cols %in% c(...)]` would be a better way to do this.

Comment: The problem here isn't the method but with c(). Your method would work (and is more efficient), but it still doesn't recognize c() and gave me same error message

Comment: obviously it doesn't solve your problem. That's why it's a tip in a comment. See my answer for a solution to your real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error cannot be reproduced. I tried everything possible to get the same output, but the code keeps running perfectly fine.

The error you get, is not generated by the `c()` function itself. At least, not by the `c()` function from the base package. But these kinds of errors are typical when you mask the `c()` function by another function (or reactive expression).

So while you didn't add that code, I'm rather sure you did something like this:

```
> library(shiny)
> c <- reactive({NULL})
> c(2012,2)
Error in c(2012, 2) : unused arguments (2012, 2)
```

Obviously the `NULL` can be anything else. The problem is that the reactive expression is a function in itself, and this function masks the base `c()` function. That's the only way you can get this kind of error with the `c()` function.

So the obvious solution is to make sure you don't give objects the same name as common functions, especially not when creating them as reactive expressions. In case you insist on using `c` as a reactive expression or so of some kind, you can use `base::c()` if you want to use the R function itself.

```
> c <- reactive({NULL})
> base::c(2012,2)
[1] 2012    2
```

Comment: Hooo ! Thanks you'are 100% right ! I've put some variables exemples named a, b and...  c of course without thinking that it would mask the c function. Thank you so much I wouldn't found the solution. (And sorry for my bad english).